# How to align a box at middle of page without using margin?

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to get a box at middle of page without using margin.

I tried-

```
.box-middle
{
vertical-align:middle;
height:100px;
width:100px;
border:1px solid #ddd;

}
```

This doesn't work at all-

But things with setting up margin property works and i don't want to use `margin`. 
Because giving margin breaks responsive web design.

So i have a login form and want to set it at middle of page.

Please guide !

Here you can do tricks with this box-

[Please align me middle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/LTec3/)

Comment: any reason for not using margin? put a container and on child container put margin left right to auto

Comment: What do you mean 'breaks responsive web design'? I'd assume it would enhance it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following jQuery code :

```
  $(window).resize(function(){

  $('.className').css({
    position:'absolute',
    left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
    top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
  });

  });
```

// To initially run the function:

```
 $(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTec3/3/)

```
.box-middle
 {
 text-align:center;
 margin: 50px auto;
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #ddd;
background:#98bf26;

 }

<div style="border:1px solid">
 <div class="box-middle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.box-middle
{
margin-top:-50px;/*half the box's height*/
    margin-left:-50px;/*half the box's width*/
height:100px;
width:100px;
border:1px solid #ddd;
    background:#98bf26;
position: absolute;
top: 50%; left: 50%;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LTec3/1/

Comment: That's quite nice, can you bring this without margin to me?

Comment: You need the margin, why don't you want to use a margin?

Comment: Because giving margin breaks responsiveness of page.

Comment: Not in my experience, how is it breaking the responsiveness? The box here will always be in the center.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually center something with absolute position

This will make the sizing 20/60/20 and will adjust depending on the side of the user's window:

```
<DIV style="position:absolute; top:249px; left:20%; width:60%; height:700px;">
```

or

```
<DIV style="position:absolute; top:249px; left:435px; width:233px; height:700px;">
```

There is also the simple center tag:

```
<center>
```

Comment: The center tag has been depreciated. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp